# OrientDB java putIfAbsent error with Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, orientdb

Problem: I can connect to the server but NOT a database.

```
orientdb> CONNECT remote:localhost root2 admin

Connecting to remote Server instance [remote:localhost] with user 'root2'...OK
orientdb {server=remote:localhost/}> disconnect

Disconnecting from remote server [remote:localhost/]...
OK
orientdb> CONNECT remote:localhost/asdf root2 admin

Connecting to database [remote:localhost/asdf] with user 'root2'...
Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.enterprise.channel.binary.OResponseProcessingException: Exception during response processing.

Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.Map.putIfAbsent(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

I'm using:
OrientDB v2.1.6
Java v1.7.0_91 (Ubuntu v14.04 does not offer Java v1.8 yet).

Does Java v.1.8 solve this problem?

Comment: You could also use OrientDB v2.1.7 or major that solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

YES. Upgrading to Java v.1.8 solves this problem.

Q: But how do you install Java v1.8 in Ubuntu v14.04 when it is not offered?
A:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java<br>
$ sudo apt-get update<br>
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer<br>
$ java -version<br>
```

see: http://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-8-jdk-8-ubuntu-via-ppa